# Generate sheet separated excel with GridView in MVC web enviroment

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, datagridview

I use the following code, and I'm wondering if I can somehow make this a sheet separated excel file with each row in its own sheet.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlConnection objcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
string sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

SqlDataAdapter objda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, objcon);
objda.Fill(dt);

GridView gvreport = new GridView();
gvreport.DataSource = dt;
gvreport.DataBind();

string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss");

string fileName = string.Format("TheFilename_{0}.xls", date);

Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gvreport.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();

return null;
```

I know that this doesn't exactly generate a real excel file but rather tricks the browser to create one. Which is probably why its a bit more complicated to make advanced excel files.
I've already tried with things like setting a max amount of rows per gridview page and so on.

Are there any way of doing this, or in general create an excel file in another way that allows me to do this. Without needing Windows office or similar installed.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like [OpenXML](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670141/Read-and-Write-Microsoft-Excel-with-Open-XML-SDK).  I'm guess the reason your creating the excel file on the fly is because you don't want to use interop objects because they are too heavy and bulky. However you still need the flexibility to manipulate objects.  I would look at the OpenXML library as it contains many of the manipulations that your looking for the code would look something like below to get you started.  In the above link you'll notice there is an example for mvc.  Which really doesn't change the underlying code much.

```
 using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filename, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {

                  WorkbookPart workBookPart = spreadSheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();

                  WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workBookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();

                  WorkbookStylesPart workBookStylesPart = workBookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
                  Stylesheet stylesheet = new CustomStyleSheet();
                  stylesheet.Save(workBookStylesPart);

                  string relId = workBookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart);

                  Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

                  Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet();

                   var columns = CreateColumns();

                  Sheets sheets = new Sheets();
                  Sheet sheet = new Sheet { Name = "mySheet", SheetId = 1, Id = relId };
                  sheets.Append(sheet);

                   worksheet.Append(columns);

                   SheetData sheetData = CreateSheetData();
                   worksheet.Append(sheetData);
                   workbook.Append(sheets);

                  worksheetPart.Worksheet = worksheet;
                  worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();             

                  spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook = workbook;
                  spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();

                  //Now I want to add an empty sheet                      
                 sheet = new Sheet { Name = "mySheet2", SheetId = 2, Id = relId };
                 sheets.Append(sheet);



                 spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
                 spreadSheetDocument.Close();

       }
```

Comment: Its mostly because of some interop requiring office to be installed which I have no control over.
But I'm gonna check this out and come back later